Data from the Notion API not updating when deployed NextJS app on Vercel
I have a blog application in NextJS that takes the posts content from the Notion API. It works perfectly running on localhost, I make changes in Notion and they are loaded normally. But using the Vercel production deploy, the changes are not loaded when there are changes in Notion. What could be happening?
Github link: https://github.com/ewrtonl/ewerton.dev
I have no idea how to solve this problem and I tried deploying it directly through Vercel instead of committing it through Github and then deploying it, it didn't work either.
import { Client } from "@notionhq/client";
import { NotionDatabaseResponse } from "../_types/notion";

const notion = new Client({ auth: process.env.NOTION_API_KEY });

export async function getPosts() {
  const databaseId = process.env.NOTION_DATABASE_ID || "";
  const response = await notion.databases.query({
    database_id: databaseId,
    filter: {
      or: [
        {
          property: "published",
          checkbox: {
            equals: true,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  });

  const typedResponse = (response as unknown) as NotionDatabaseResponse;

  return typedResponse.results.map((post) => {
    return {
      id: post.id,
      title: post.properties.title.title[0].plain_text,
      slug: post.properties.slug.rich_text[0].plain_text,
      tags: post.properties.tags.multi_select.map((tag) => tag.name),
      createdAt: post.created_time,
    };
  })
}


When deploying a nextJS project the project is built using the npm run build command, which tries to generate your pages in a static manner and caches these. Next runs the getPosts() function while building and caches the resulting page, but doesnt run this function ever again.
You have to explicitly state that this page is not to be statically rendered.You can do this by putting:


export default async function Page(){
    //do whatever you want with the data
    const posts = getPosts();
    ...
}



in your page.tsx file.
